# Access rights for the users in a team

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I have users in a team having access to particular fields on lead, opportunity and account entities. I have few users who are in team they just need access to fields on lead and Opportunity entity not on account ?

I thought Ill use field level security on the fields to achieve this, having field level security will have effect other functionality in the system. Any thoughts on how to achieve this ?

Comment: Create 3 field level security profile, and add user who want access to the fields

Answer (score 0):

Breaking down CRM security levels:

1. Role level - Entity level (e.g. access to Lead but not marketing list)
2. Record level - Read/Write/Access (e.g. read lead record but not modify them)
3. Field level - Field level show/hide (e.g. hide a lead's account field for certain users or team).

In your case, it depends on what defines having access (is it more of a don't need to see or a should not see scenario). If it is just a case of a set of users don't have to deal with certain fields use different CRM forms for different teams, if it is a case of they should not be seeing the data use field level security.

This also would hopefully answer "having field level security will have effect other functionality in the system?" questions, if field level security is implemented, the fields which are restricted read won't show up in the advanced find queries or reports for the users who are not assigned the field level security profiles. Also once you have secured the field, every new user or team needs the field level security profile assigned, else they won't be able to see the field.